# Origin of "machine" in SVM, GBM etc

Tags: terminology, definition

Is it known who originally introduced the term "machine" used in terms like

- machine learning,
- support vector machine or
- gradient boosting machine?

Could it be defined as an "algorithm that fits a statistical model"?  OLS could then be called "least squares machine"...

Is there an official definition of the word "machine" in statistics?

Comment: I believe "Gradient Boosting Machine" comes from Friedman's paper: https://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/trebst.pdf